# Why are functions bound to the first type they are passed

Tags: f#

I'm new to F#. I was messing around and I found something interesting and I was hoping someone could enlighten me as to what is going on behind the scenew.

So I made the function: `let my_func (x, y) = x + y`.

Then I called the function with the args `1` and `2` giving me `3`. This is what I expected to happen but when I passed two strings to `my_func` I got an error even though `+` is a valid operator with strings. I reran my code but this time only calling `my_func` with `"cat"` and `" dog"` which gave me `"cat dog"`. I then tried to pass `1` and `2` back to `my_func` only to find that `my_func` no long accepts integers.

Why is `my_func` behaving this way?

`let my_func (x, y) = x + y`
`my_func (1, 2)           //  produces => 3` 
`my_func ("cat", " dog")  // Error`

**rerun program**...

`let my_func (x, y) = x + y`
`my_func ("cat", " dog")  //  produces => "cat dog"`
`my_func (1, 2)           //  Error`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@MarcinJuraszek showed you how to solve this issue but said nothing about *why* it happens.

You can think of it like this:

F#'s type inference works *top to bottom*, *left to right* - so when the system tries to find the type for `my_func` it will find assign the types from the first line where you are using the function  (first example it is `int`s and the second is `string`s) - If you don't use it at all or define it in FSharp Interactive it will indeed default to `int`.

Declaring the function as `inline` enables F# to use [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) (due to some details this is only possible with `inline` functions) and then it will indeed do something like *duck-typing* to figure out from the declaration that the function needs types where a static `+` operator is defined somehow.

You can see this in the type of the function:

```
val inline my_func :
  x: ^a * y: ^b ->  ^c
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

this rather complicated type says just this:

There must be a static operator `(+) : ^a * ^b -> ^c` on `^a` (think `'a`) that is used when you write `+` in the functions body. As you can see this is even more generic than you really need it but this is no issue. F# will implement concrete versions (with the generic types substituted) for ever occurrence of this function you apply (so in your example there will be two `my_func` instantiations in your IL; one for `Int`s and one for `String`s) - but this won't bother you at design-time at all.

So you now have a more *generic* function that can be used with:

- `(+) : Int * Int -> Int` on `Int`
- `(+) : String * String -> String` on `String`

Comment: +1 great answer. Se also [this article by Liam MCLennnan covering similar ground](http://withouttheloop.com/articles/2014-10-21-fsharp-adhoc-polymorphism/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your method using `inline` keyword to make it work:

```
let inline my_func (x,y) = x + y
```

Read more on MSDN: [Inline Functions (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx)